# Why don't tags in a separate Mercurial branch work?

Tags: mercurial, tags, branch

I'm setting up a Mercurial repository to track third-party code, roughly following the vendor-default branch scheme described in Rudi's answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3997600/vendor-branching-mercurial-style).  In order to quickly retrieve a particular version, I create tags for each vendor and default version.

I initialize the repo by committing an empty .hgtags to establish the default branch, then I `hg branch vendor` and import the first version.  The process to add a new version looks like this:

```
hg up -C vendor
... load new version ...
hg commit -A -m "Adding version x.y.x"
hg tag vendor-x.y.z
hg up -C default
hg merge vendor
hg commit -m "Merging version x.y.z"
hg tag x.y.z
```

During the merge I always keep the local copy of .hgtags, so the result is that the vendor branch has .hgtags containing all the vendor-x.y.z tags while the default branch .hgtags has only the x.y.z tags.

It's my understanding that Mercurial considers .hgtags from all heads when working with tags.  Yet when I run `hg tags` the result contains only tip and the x.y.z tags.  This is the same regardless of which branch my working directory is updated to; it's always the tags from the default branch .hgtags file.

I can update to the vendor-x.y.z tags, so Mercurial does see their existence, but the update appears to give me code from the vendor branch tip.  The x.y.z tags work fine.

I've worked mainly with Git and SVN/CVS in the past, so I assume that this is a problem of understanding, not a technical issue.  I did try it, just in case, on two versions of Mercurial (2.0.2 and 2.3.2) and got the same results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not in front of my Mercurial system to verify, but I think the issue is Mercurial only considers .hgtags from topological heads, not branch heads.  Example:

```
[1]---[2]---[5]---[6]    Default
        \         /
         [3]---[4]       Vendor
```

[6] is a topological head, [4] and [6] are branch heads.  The solution is to keep all changes to .hgtags on a merge.

**Edit**

Here's my test.  Directly after the merge I accepted the local .hgtags and `hg tags` only displays the tag on `default`.  I can't update to the vendor tag, which differs from what you are seeing.  I'm using Mercurial 2.3.1.  After creating another changeset on vendor and making a second topological head, the missing tag reappears.

```
hg init test
cd test
echo >a
hg ci -Am 1
hg branch vendor
echo >b
hg ci -Am 2
hg tag v1
hg update default
hg tag d1
hg merge vendor --tool internal:local
hg ci -m Merge

@REM This only shows 'tip' and 'd1'
hg tags

hg update vendor
hg tags
hg update d1

@REM This fails to update.
hg update v1

@ Add another topological head by committing to vendor
hg update vendor
echo >c
hg ci -Am 3

@ Now all tags are visible and work.
hg tags
hg update v1
hg update d1
```

And the output:

```
C:\>hg init test
C:\>cd test
C:\test>echo  1>a
C:\test>hg ci -Am 1
adding a
C:\test>hg branch vendor
marked working directory as branch vendor
(branches are permanent and global, did you want a bookmark?)
C:\test>echo  1>b
C:\test>hg ci -Am 2
adding b
C:\test>hg tag v1
C:\test>hg update default
0 files updated, 0 files merged, 2 files removed, 0 files unresolved
C:\test>hg tag d1
C:\test>hg merge vendor --tool internal:local
1 files updated, 1 files merged, 0 files removed, 0 files unresolved
(branch merge, don't forget to commit)
C:\test>hg ci -m Merge
C:\test>hg tags
tip                                4:80759c41b3cc
d1                                 0:17b05ed457d1
C:\test>hg update vendor
1 files updated, 0 files merged, 0 files removed, 0 files unresolved
C:\test>hg tags
tip                                4:80759c41b3cc
d1                                 0:17b05ed457d1
C:\test>hg update d1
0 files updated, 0 files merged, 2 files removed, 0 files unresolved
C:\test>hg update v1
abort: unknown revision 'v1'!
C:\test>hg update vendor
2 files updated, 0 files merged, 0 files removed, 0 files unresolved
C:\test>echo  1>c
C:\test>hg ci -Am 3
adding c
C:\test>hg tags
tip                                5:a2c0fe73a9f1
v1                                 1:3168d0f4e5e5
d1                                 0:17b05ed457d1
C:\test>hg update v1
0 files updated, 0 files merged, 2 files removed, 0 files unresolved
C:\test>hg update d1
0 files updated, 0 files merged, 1 files removed, 0 files unresolved
```

Comment: That would make sense, but how would that produce the behavior where Mercurial allow me to update to one of those other tags (doesn't produce the 'no such tag' error) while actually updating to the tip of that branch?

Comment: I added an example that confirms the behavior I guessed at.  Can you reproduce the behavior you are seeing and update your question?  Still, the answer is to merge .hgtags normally.  That's the standard thing to do.